# Disable all options selected in other elements

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am trying to disable an option if it has been selected in any of the other select elements, and re-enable it if it gets unselected.

This function isn't working properly when I preselect options `(selected="selected")`, and only works for one option at a time amongst all the select elements. How can I modify it to work with preselected options and for all of the options amongst all the elements?

I posted a fiddle of the function without any preselected options here: http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/927/

JS

```
$('.rank_options').change(function() { 
    $('#priority1, #priority2, #priority3, #priority4, #priority5').not(this)
    .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
    .attr('disabled', true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');    
});
```

HTML

```
<tr >        
<td><select name=priority1 id="priority1" class="rank_options" >
    <option selected="selected" value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option> 
    <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option> 
    <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option></select> 
</td>
<td ><select name=priority2 id="priority2" class="rank_options" >
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option> 
    <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option> 
    <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option></select>  
</td>
<td><select name=priority3 id="priority3" class="rank_options" >
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="Test 3">Test 3</option> 
    <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option> 
    <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option></select> 
</td>
<td><select name=priority4 id="priority4" class="rank_options" >
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="Test 4">Test 4</option> 
    <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option></select>                          
</td>
<td><select name=priority5 id="priority5" class="rank_options" >
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option> 
    <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="Test 5">Test 5</option></select> 
</td>       
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select option[value="Test 1"]').attr('disabled',true);
});
$('.rank_options').change(function () {
  $('#priority1, #priority2, #priority3, #priority4, #priority5').
  find('option:selected').each(function(){
   $("#priority1, #priority2, #priority3, #priority4, #priority5").find("option[value="+this.value+"]").attr('disabled', true);
   });
});
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/933/)

Comment: Yes :-D Any idea how I can get that to work with preselected options?

Comment: The only preselected option is Test 1, then this already do it, or maybe you mean anything else? If you want add some other preselected options add in ready(function(){... other attribute disabled as for "Test 1"

Comment: I'm preselecting one option in most of the Select elements (I have that in the code I posted, but not in the fiddle because I can't get it to work with it)